# In what way did Dennis Ritchie influence you?

Tags: discussion

How did the work of [Dennis Ritchie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dennis_Ritchie) (1941-2011) influence you as a programmer? Of course, there are the obvious things (C, Unix). For me, the biggest thing (other than coding in C, on Unix, for years) was the writing style in [The C Programming Language ("K&R")](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language_(book)), which was remarkably terse and yet very clear.

Did you know that very early versions of C used `i =- 2;` as the syntax for subtracting 2 from i, instead of `i -= 2`? And the trouble of course is that then `i =- 2` would have a different meaning from `i = -2`, a dangerous whitespace sensitivity. And if you find yourself nodding along with me, remembering this old syntax which never actually saw the light of day outside of Bell Labs, it's because it's reported at the very end of K&R, and you read that because K&R was so dang short that you ran out of things to read before you ran out of patience with the book, and that in itself is a testament to the bold, clean simplicity of the C language.

Comment: Is this a real question for meta?

Comment: Yes. I thought it would be respectful to take some time today to pause and reflect on a great man who passed away and why he was influential.

Comment: Okay. Do not think it has meant to be offensive. I just thought it could fit up for programmers/stackoverflow itself

Comment: Well *you* made me read his book, who has had more influence on me: you or him?

Comment: Without him, obviously I wouldn't be the programmer pedantry nerd at work.

Comment: Is this not a question about the people on Stackoverflow!?

Comment: This is getting ridiculous - this question will be closed for the second time and probably reopened again right after. Does locking a post prevent close / reopen votes?

Comment: @George: yes. But at this point, doing so is probably pointless. I re-opened (and deleted a fair number of comments) because the whole sour grapes "we're not getting a banner so let's piss on any other tribute" attitude of the closers and commenters disgusted me. But it doesn't appear anyone is interested in doing anything productive here, so might as well let the topic rest.

Comment: @Shog9: That's too bad. I was hoping to see some nice stories here.

Comment: Wow, this is the best you can do @JoelSpolsky, after your last banner? Just wow.

Comment: @Shog9: seriously? You think off-topic question on MSO is the right place for this?

Comment: No, actually *I* think a big image featuring Professor Farnsworth is the *classy* way to go on this @vartec... But I'm fine with this too.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109160

Answer (score 18):

This tribute has a rather serious problem: as [Dennis pointed out years ago](https://web.archive.org/web/20080309205352/http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/who/dmr/chist.html):

> Although we worked closely together on this book, there was a clear division of labor: Kernighan wrote almost all the expository material, while I was responsible for the appendix containing the reference manual and the chapter on interfacing with the Unix system.

If we're going to go into bits of personal history about Dennis though, perhaps I'll throw out one little bit from long ago on Usenet. The story starts with Clive D.W. Feather saying:

> Dennis: *please* tell this person how wrong he is.

...and rather than giving Dennis time to reply himself, I jumped in with a post that started out:

> It hardly seems necessary.  A couple of quotes from the preface to the second edition should suffice:

Dennis added [a reply](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.unix.bsd.freebsd.misc/msg/2de823fadd0f0c08) saying:

> Nowadays I can have other people do this for me, as later messages (Coffin, da Silva) did.  (I suppose I better say :) just in case).

So, Dennis influenced me to quit using quotes from him to tell people they're full of garbage, as long as he was alive. Hopefully I can be forgiven for doing so now.

Comment: wow, you are a legend too then.

Comment: There are also [practical jokes](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fxMKuv0A6z4) worth mentioning .. since this is closed. I'm not making light of his death, but that was just really darn funny.

Comment: @Jerry, Your links are down..........

Comment: @Pacerier: Repaired (I think). You'd think even the current management of Bell Labs would realize it was worth preserving Dennis' home page, but you'd apparently be wrong...

Comment: @JerryCoffin, That's why I always use web.archive.org and archive.is