# Please do something special for Aaron Swartz account

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How should a user’s death be handled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38742/how-should-a-users-death-be-handled)

As we all know, [Aaron Swartz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aaron_Swartz) was found dead in his apartment. Aaron committed suicide probably because of the court case againist the government.

Please do something special [his Stackoverflow account](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4300/aaronsw). That's only thing what I want to wish.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure this is really a dupe, as your request is different and more specific, but my answer here covers our feelings on this. We had the same instinct you did, but concluded that it wasn't the right thing to do:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164749/147336

Comment: The question was a general discussion @Jaydles, about what should be done in the event of a user passing. Though this is a more specific it's covered wholly by the dupe where you've already provided a "canonical" answer... Rather than having a new question for each person on the network who passes away I think it's better to point people toward the question where the SE team has already made a decision..? Or not :-)?

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards, you're right - I was thinking of the usefulness of this question to those searching for this specifically, but you're clearly correct that one set of *answers* is what's needed here.

Comment: There are some related discussions at [Dennis Ritchie goes into the night without a quote on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/109160/131713) (and its linked posts) from about a year and a half ago, when Steve Jobs and Dennis Ritchie died.

Comment: Academic journals are unbelievably scummy -- good for this guy for trying to do something about it.

Comment: There was talk among the moderators to reach out to his family and see if they wished for something in his profile page to direct people to his memorial, or other sites where actionable things are going on surrounding the circumstances of his death. I don't know if that actually _happened_ though, @Shog9 might be able to shed some light there. To be clear, this was more about giving the family _access_ to that text, not creating a memorial out of the account.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If he didn't ask anybody to do anything with his account, I don't think we should assume he wanted anything to be done. Even though this is something you wish for, I don't think it was something *he* wished for — and the best way to pay tribute to him, I feel, would be to respect *his* wishes (and those of his loved ones as well of course).